# Sum of Multiples

Tags: haskell, exercism

A different approach than [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/94193/sum-arithmetic-progression-in-haskell), this time without using arithmetic progression. The [README](http://exercism.io/exercises/haskell/sum-of-multiples/readme) specs both `sumOfMultiples` and `sumOfMultiplesDefault` and the code passes the [test suit](http://exercism.io/exercises/haskell/sum-of-multiples).

```
module SumOfMultiples
    (sumOfMultiples
    ,sumOfMultiplesDefault
    ) where

sumOfMultiples :: [Integer] -> Integer -> Integer
sumOfMultiples factors limit =
  sum $ filter (`divByAny` factors) [1..end]
  where
    divBy a b  = a `rem` b == 0
    divByAny x = any (x `divBy`)
    end        = limit - 1

sumOfMultiplesDefault :: Integer -> Integer
sumOfMultiplesDefault = sumOfMultiples [3,5]
```

I am mainly concerned with the readability of

```
sum $ filter (`divByAny` factors) [1..end]
```

and

```
divByAny x = any (x `divBy`)
```

and if there is a performance issue (besides using `Int` instead of `Integer`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid sections by swapping arguments:

```
sumOfMultiples :: [Integer] -> Integer -> Integer
sumOfMultiples factors limit =
  sum $ filter (divByAny factors) [1..end]
  where
    divBy b a = a `rem` b == 0
    divByAny l x = any (divBy x) l
    end        = limit - 1
```

Performance can be improved significantly by using a different algorithm. E.g by constructing an infinite list of all the multiples and taking a partial sum of it.

It is also possible to make code polymorphic (working with both `Int` and `Integer`) by changing the type to the inferred one.

Comment: I'm not sure constructing that list efficiently would be terribly easy. If you build one for each factor, then you have to remove duplicates when merging them.